# Tasks for build and run works but executing with the generated run script doesn't

Tags: java, linux, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am doing the simple HelloWorld example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/.

I had to do some changes (I'm using Gradle 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 18) to the `build.gradle`. I used gradlew wrapper. I managed to get tasks like 'build' and 'run' working. Everything is generated correctly, it seems. But running the app without gradle using the generated `build/scripts/<appscript>` does not work. Running the jar with

```
java -jar build/libs/hello-1.0.jar
```

works. But

```
./build/scripts/sayhello
```

Does not work and produces an error:

```
erno@moongate:~/Projects/java/sayhello$ ./build/scripts/sayhello 
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.HelloWorld
```

Project file structure is as suggested:

```
sayhello/
    build.gradle
    gradlew
    src/
        main/
        java/
        hello/
            Greeter.java
            HelloWorld.java
```

I had to add the manifest and the mainclass attribute to the build configuration file as it seems that the `gradle init --type java-application` does not do it. Meaning that even trying to run the gradle generated base project does not work.

My `build.gradle` is like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.10"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'hello.HelloWorld'
        )
    }
    baseName = 'hello'
    version = '1.0'
}
```

Comment: I added a settings.gradle file to override the default behaviour and now instead of sayhello* it creates hello* for the compile artifacts. And now running the generated jar does not work anymore. I'm not sure if it's caused by my recent modification or something else.

Comment: This project can be found in git: https://github.com/codesmith-fi/hello

Comment: Just a side note: Java 8 has a time API that replaces joda time. Aka joda time is deprecated by java 8

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `startScripts` task is that it generates a very basic script. It does not make sure dependent jars are in the right places - it expects this to be done by you. Also it assumes that you will be running the script from a directory it refers to as the `$APP_HOME` and this folder needs to contain a `lib` folder which contains all the jars your app needs.

My very hacky solution is to generate an even more basic unix script instead of relying on the default one.

```
startScripts {
    dependsOn jar
    doFirst {
        unixStartScriptGenerator = configure(new CustomUnixStartScript()) {
            classpath = configurations.runtimeClasspath + jar.outputs.files
        }
    }
}

class CustomUnixStartScript implements ScriptGenerator {
    @InputFiles
    FileCollection classpath

    @Override
    void generateScript (JavaAppStartScriptGenerationDetails details, Writer destination) {
        destination << """java -classpath $classpath.asPath ${details.mainClassName}"""
    }
}
```

You can extend this as you see fit.